# Empty global temporary table in oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm porting some triggers from SQL server to Oracle. There is a query based on the data that's being deleted, and the sql server operation is something like:

```
SELECT a, b 
INTO #my_temp_table 
FROM
(
    SELECT A, B, C, D
    FROM DELETED D
    INNER JOIN MYTABLE M ON D.ID = M.ID
)
```

The real query is very complicated and I don't know what it's really doing, so I am not able to do any edits.

I was looking for a similar structure in Oracle, and I found the GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE, so I did something like

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
AS
    SELECT A, B, C, D
    FROM MYTABLE
```

which is actually working fine.

My problem is when the query is not returning any data, I get an `ORA-01723: zero-length columns are not allowed`.
Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: `SELECT COALESCE(A, CAST(NULL AS datatype<length>)) AS A, ... FROM DELETED D ...`?

Comment: I'm sorry what is `datatype<length>`?

Comment: Your datatype for each column like `INT/NUMBER/VARCHAR2(100)` and so on

Comment: Now I understand, but my problem is that an empty resultset cannot be inserted into a temporary table. The query is returning no data. This hasn't fixed the problem

Comment: Yeah I did, but the error keeps firing

Comment: I just read the documentation of global temporary tables.  There, the table is created first and the rows are inserted afterwards.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow what you are doing.  Oracle does not provide a `deleted` pseudo-table in a trigger.  If you want row-level data, you'd use the `:new` or `:old` pseudo-record in a row-level trigger.  Unless you created `deleted` as a new global temporary table and populated it in a row-level trigger so that you can use `my_temp_table` in statement-level trigger, I don't see how the code you posted could compile

Comment: @JustinCave you're right, I posted the wrong example. I solved that part anyway, there's not a problem.

Comment: @DanBracuk you're right too, because trying a different example worked with an empty resultset. Why that error, though?

Comment: Why would you create a temporary table that just has a point-in-time copy of the data in a permanent table?  That seems unlikely to be the correct approach.  In the actual code that throws the error just using straight column names like the updated example?  Or does it possibly have an expression that might be causing the error?  Posting a reproducible test case (a set of statements we can run in our database that replicates the problem) would be very helpful here.

Comment: I said that the actual query is very complicated. It's about 100 lines, with joins to 6-7 tables, it's hard to make a reproducible test case

Comment: But do you need 100 lines and 6 joins to reproduce the problem?  The point of a reproducible test case is to find the smallest piece of code that reproduces the problem.  Unfortunately, as it sits, there is no plausible way that the code you posted would cause the error you posted.  I would strongly suspect that some aspect of the problem that you removed when posting your example is the root cause of your error.  Since we don't know what you removed, it's not very productive to guess what the error might be.

Comment: I really appreciate your interest in solving my problem, but I already found the solution. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that one column was calculated as `NULL`, and this kind of columns cannot be inserted into temp tables in oracle. I also tried with `''` but it gives me the same error.
So it was

```
SELECT A, B, null as C, D
    FROM MYTABLE
```

and I changed it to

```
SELECT A, B, 0 as C, D
    FROM MYTABLE
```